# What Issues could arise, when reading/writing to a single shard in a sharded MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In the offical MongoDB Documentation it is stated that:
"Clients should never connect to a single shard in order to perform read or write operations." [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)

I did try writing some data to a single shard node and it worked, but it is not a big dataset (certainly not one that would require sharding).
Could this lead to other issues, which I am not yet aware of?
Or are clients discouraged from doing this, simply because of performance reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sharded cluster, the individual shards contain the data but some of the operation state is stored on `mongos` nodes. When you communicate with individual shards you bypass `mongos`es and as such any state management that they would perform.

Depending on the operation, this could be innocuous or could result in unexpected behavior/wrong results.

There isn't a comprehensive list of issues that would arise because the scenario of direct shard access isn't tested (because it's not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, by default you don't know which data portion is stored on which shard. The balancer is running in background and may change the data distribution at any time.

If you insert some data manually into one shard, then a properly connected client may not find this data.

If you read some data from a single shard then you don't know whether this data is complete or not.